# How can I generate random answer string like "yes,no,maybe maybe not?

Tags: linux, shell-script, terminal, string

I dont know how can I generate random answer.

exemple result:

```
user:~$ ./question.sh do you love me ?
user:~$ yes
```

or

```
user:~$ ./question.sh do you hate me ?
user:~$ maybe
```

I try to put all the String in a variable like :

```
d='yes','no','maybe' etc..
but the message errors is always : impossible : not found
```

Comment: Traditionally, when folks have a problem they want help with, they post their code, which I don't see here. Please click [edit] and add the contents of _question.sh_  so we may provide assistance.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash

array=( yes no maybe )
read -p 'do you hate me ? [press a key] >>> '
echo ${arr[RANDOM % ${#array[@]}]}
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888735/creating-a-bash-script-that-acts-as-a-fortune-teller-or-magic-8-ball-essential and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157546/create-a-magic-8-ball